# Raspberry PI 3 does not intall on SDCard

Tags: raspberry-pi3, sd-card

So I did everything that was written in the internet. Formating SD with SD Card Formatter, installing raspberry pi OS with Raspberry Pi Imager and balenaEtcher, and everytime it gives me error, like boot part is installed, but the other side does not. It gives error such as Access Denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk utilities:

1. diskpart
2. list disk
3. select disk RPi
4. clean
   Then install with Raspberry Pi Image and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think that SD card is damaged or something may be wrong with write protection (readonly) switch on SD.

Comment: so the main issue is that SD Card Formatter works, and when you formeted SD Card you can upload and delete files from that SD Card so I think damaged is not issue

Comment: Maybe try to make full format (not quick). Also you can take a look if sd card connector on RPi is not damaged.

Comment: so like general issue I checked already and it seems fine, the main problem is that when I am installing Raspberry Pi OS on SD Card it creates 2 types of disk, one is Boot which is installed correct, but the second type is gived as Access Denied